# Using Spring Cloud Task in order to run tasks on a tasks-enabled Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-task

I am using the latest [Pivotal Cloud Foundry](https://run.pivotal.io/), i.e *version 1.8*.

Running `cf feature-flags` indicates that tasks creation is indeed enabled.

My Spring app is using the latest [Spring Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/) library, i.e. *version 1.1.0.RELEASE*, and tasks are enabled by `@EnableTask` annotation.

However, when I `cf push` the app, it is restarted as if it were treated as a LRP (Long Running Process) and not as a task...

Can someone please help? What I am missing?

**edit**: The latest version of PWS Cloud Foundry is now: **1.9** but my question remains relevant.

Comment: My question remains...  The latest CLI can now run tasks on PWS but the documentation does not state how to `cf push` a task app without it being picked up as a web process... Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to `cf push` an application without it being picked up as a web/LRP process, one has to pass in the `--no-route` argument to `cf push`.

There is a `no-route: true` equivalent if one uses a `manifest.yml`.

Comment: I am getting same issue, app getting restarted even though I specify no-route: true in my manifest file. Anything Do I need to do @balteo

Comment: Set your instance count to 0

Answer (score 2):

Tasks can be created using the API (http://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.0.0/index.html#the-task-object) and from mid-Dec with the cf CLI (`cf run-task`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. The mid-December `cf run-task` is excellent news! I am still wondering though what the whole process looks like: how do I `cf push` an task app (to be run later on with `cf run-task`) without it being picked up as a LRP? Can you point to the documentation about the `cf run-task`?

Comment: OK. Regarding the documentation, it seems it is currently being worked by the Pivotal team and will soon be available.

Comment: **Update:** here is the link to the documentation about running tasks: http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-9/devguide/using-tasks.html

Comment: **Update**: the latest CLI now allows for task running with `cf run-task APP_NAME COMMAND [--name TASK_NAME]`. However the documentation does not state what command to pass in order to run the java executable (for a batch app for example). I have opened a another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313079/