# Accessing the java executable from a cloudfoundry task command (cf run-task)

Tags: buildpack, cloud-foundry

I need the java executable to run a java -jar from a **cloudfoundry task** command.

Here is how I try to run the task:

```
cf run-task bignibou-batch "java -jar bignibou-batch/build/libs/bignibou-batch.jar"
```

Here is the error message I get:

```
2016-12-24T12:53:30.002+01:00 [APP/TASK/358e02df/0] [ERR] bash: java: command not found
```

My manifest uses the java buildpack as follows (see `bignibou-batch` app at the bottom):

```
---
buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
memory: 1024M
env:
  APPLICATION_URL: http://bignibou-server.cfapps.io/
  APPLICATION_MAIL_NO_REPLY_ADDRESS: balteo@bignibou-server.cfapps.io
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: cloud

applications:
  - name: bignibou-server
    path: bignibou-server/build/libs/bignibou-server.jar
    env:
      APPLICATION_GOOGLE_API_KEY: *******************
  - name: bignibou-batch
    path: bignibou-batch/build/libs/bignibou-batch.jar
    no-hostname: true
    no-route: true
    env:
      JAVA_OPTS: -Dspring.batch.job.names=messagesDigestMailingJob
```

**edit**: When I try to set the location of the java buildpack as follows:

```
cf run-task bignibou-batch "$PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java -jar bignibou-batch/build/libs/bignibou-batch.jar"
```

The `$PWD` variable is resolved on my local machine before the command is sent...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, we consider the location of the installed JRE, as well as the command required to run the application, an internal detail subject to change without compatibility restrictions.  To the best of my knowledge (running the Java Buildpack team for nearly four years) there are no contractual obligations requiring droplets to be mounted at `/home/vcap` either, which is why we're very careful to use `$PWD` in our commands.

Other early users of Java-based tasks have allowed staging to happen completely (which would ensure that things like memory calculation and `JAVA_OPTS` are properly placed in the command) and then use that command line without modification.

The issue you're seeing with `$PWD` being resolved early is one of escaping more than anything else.  The first change you should probably make is to switch from double quotes (`"`) to single quotes (`'`) which should ensure that `$` isn't resolved immediately.  It's possible that somewhere else in the pipeline the environment is resolved again early possibly necessitating a `\$` escape, but I'd hold off on that until you're sure that you're seeng it.

Comment: Hi. I have opened a question related to the cf java buildpack here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009633 Can you kindly have a look at it?

Comment: On a sidenote, make sure that you are using the correct buildkit path. Some answers have `/open_jdk_jre/` listed, but it can also be `/oracle_jre/` if your organization pays for it. If you're unsure, you can run this command and you should be able to see your buildpack home: `cf set-env <APP-NAME> JBP_LOG_LEVEL DEBUG`.

Answer (score 4):

To execute a spring task I found this useful:

```
cf run-task vc-billing-task '$PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $PWD/. org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher' --name "vc-billing-task"
```

Just make sure your java/build-pack is updated to your specifics

Answer (score -1):

The java executable can be found here (assuming the java buildback is used):

```
cf run-task bignibou-batch '$PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java -jar bignibou-batch/build/libs/bignibou-batch.jar'
```

However, I am not sure this is the best way to run a java command for a task application...

*P.S. Please feel free to add your own answer if you think it is better than this one.*

**edit**: I have edited the path and replaced the hard coded app directory with the `$PWD` variable.

Comment: Like Ben Hale said, it is not clear that `/home/vcap` will be guaranteed in the future.

Comment: @GlynNormington I have updated my reply to take into account Ben Hale's

Comment: Just a heads up that even the `.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre` is considered an implementation detail.  As we speak, we're discussing moving that directory to a much safer location.